# On entity save, identify the user fields that have been changed

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I have a need to track changes to users in a separate database, apart from Drupal. When a user changes their email address or their password, I need to communicate that change with a shadow table in MSSQL.

I've created an event and listener. The event is triggered by hook_entity_update. That works fine, but I don't know what was changed in that request. Is there a way to pass the value that was changed to that event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [`hook_entity_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/9.0.x) documentation:

> This hook runs once the entity storage has been updated. Note that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data. Get the original entity object from $entity->original.

In your event listener, you can compare the email/password fields on `$entity` & `$entity->original` to check if they have changed.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. I overlooked the $entity->original yesterday. That gets me what I need.